# Change IP of nodes in Oracle RAC

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, oracle-rac

I have a two node RAC database running in OEL 7 server. If there is a need to change the IP addresses of the already running server to a new one, will that hamper the functioning of the database?

What changes on the database front would I need to incorporate to implement this?

Is it even possible in the first place to run the database after changing the IPs?

Comment: Q No 1) ANS: If you follow the procedure to change the IP then there wont be any hamper in the database. Q No 2) You can use OIFCFG tool to change public and private interconnects. Q No 3) It depends on whether you have done the IP changing procedure properly or not.

Answer (score 2):

The database does not care about the IP addresses. Grid Infrastructure does. The method to change the IP addresses can be found in detail in the below MOS notes:

[How to Modify Public Network Information including VIP in Oracle Clusterware (Doc ID 276434.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=276434.1)

[How to Modify Private Network Information in Oracle Clusterware (Doc ID 283684.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=283684.1)

Comment: what about only changing the Public IPs?

Answer (score 2):

We can change IP address of public and private interfaces in the Oracle RAC environment using the Oracle supplied tool called OIFCFG(Oracle Interface Configuration). Here are some high level steps to do that.

1. Get new IP's from System Administrator
2. Stop all components
3. Check Actual Configuration
4. Delete previous RAC Interconnect Configuration
5. Redefine Private IP
6. Redefine VIP
7. Stop CRS
8. Ask Systems to change IP to the new set and reboot

Here is the link for complete reference.
[RAC, IP's Reconfiguration](https://blogs.oracle.com/AlejandroVargas/entry/rac_ips_reconfiguration_exampl)

Thanks

Comment: what about only changing the Public IPs?

Comment: If you just want to change ip without changing subnet and interface you can do that at OS level without any changes at Clusterware level. 
1. Shutdown Clusterware stack 
2. Modify the IP address at network layer, DNS and /etc/hosts file to reflect the change
3. Restart Clusterware stack

Comment: ok got it, so only for private and VIP changes, the task is exhaustive, for Public - it is straight forward correct?